# How to check Which version is installed of Web form for marketer in Sitecore 8

Tags: sitecore, version, sitecore8, web-forms-for-marketers

How I can check for WFFM version that have installed in Sitecore 8.
I was checking in List of Package inside Data/Packages folder . Is this correct way to do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found one more way All Application ==> System ==> License detail ,there i found the version of WFFM.

Answer (score 4):

That's one of the options, but it's not necessarily correct. One can upload a package to that folder but never install it.

You can also check WFFFM dlls in the `bin` folder and see their version.

And maybe the most reliable way: login to Sitecore Desktop, change database to `core` and in Content Editor find `/sitecore/system/packages/installation history` node. There should be a list of all packages which are installed in your Sitecore application including their versions.

Comment: Thanks Marek . I found one more way All Application ==> System ==> License detail ,there i found the version of WFFM. Is this correct ?

Answer (score 1):

Look in the sitecore general log at application startup, all dlls are listed including version numbers.